# JQuery each event

Tags: jquery

Есть плагин JQuery, который работает с элементами на странице.

```
(function( $ ){
$.fn.tooltip = function(options) {

    // этот код работает только с существующими элементами
    $(this).each(function (i) {
        console.log(i);
    });

    // этот код должен работать с динамическими, но не работает
    $(document).on("each", this, function (i) {
        console.log(i);
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

На странице присутствует содержимое, которое обновляется с определенным интервалом через AJAX, после этого плагин перестает работать с новыми динамическими элементами.

Comment: "должен работать", это вы так предполагаете, или где-то есть примеры, что он работает?  зы: загрузили данные по аяксу - навесили плагин на новые элементы и проблемы нет никакой  `$.get(url, function(html){ $(html).find(".some-class").tooltip( ... ); })`

Comment: то есть если вам понятно. что плагин не работает с новыми элементами - то зачем лезть внутрь плагина, если его можно подключить к этим самым новым элементам?

Comment: не работает на новых т. к. скрипт уже загружен и dom построен... Инициализируйте заново скрипт, после добавления элементов и всё будет работать

Comment: Очевидные ответы... Разумеется можно заново подключить. Но проблема в том что плагин добавляет много кода в дом, и при каждом подключении страница просто будет тормозить.